# Jupyter Notebook installation error - Building wheel for argon2-cffi (PEP 517) ... error

Tags: python, jupyter

```
Building wheels for collected packages: argon2-cffi
  Building wheel for argon2-cffi (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\prasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpcczeigwt'
       cwd: C:\Users\prasa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-iele2h25\argon2-cffi
  Complete output (17 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\low_level.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\_ffi_build.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\_legacy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\_password_hasher.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  running build_clib
  building 'argon2' library
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for argon2-cffi
Failed to build argon2-cffi
ERROR: Could not build wheels for argon2-cffi which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I installed python 3.9 on my computer. When I try to install jupyter notebook I got this error. SO how to solve this issue ?

Comment: [When to switch to Python 3.9?](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/switch-python-3.9/) You could use also contribute to the libraries and toolset

Comment: https://github.com/hynek/argon2-cffi/issues/66

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In case, you are a mac user on Intel CPUs, just check your pip version, if you are installing through the command :

```
pip install notebook
```

Upgrade your PIP, the command that worked for me:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Check if its the latest version of PIP , by using command :

```
pip --version
```

After this again, try :

```
pip install notebook
```

This time you should not see any error.

Then include ~/Library/Python/3.8/bin in your path variable.
Check if its there by :

```
echo $PATH
```

And then launch the jupyter notebook by command :

```
jupyter notebook
```

Pls upvote, if you found this answer useful :)

Comment: Amazingly, this worked for me. I went from system pip3 version of 20.x to 21.3.1, and the wheels installed fine.

Comment: @blahblahetcetc : Pls upvote the answer, if you found it useful, thanks :)

Comment: Worked for me as well!

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same issue as you. This is how I solved it.

I found the answer here: https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/having-trouble-installing-jupyter-notebooks/537292/2

You can use the link and follow the instructions if you'd like. I'll also tell you how to do it here.

It's an easy fix. The error is about the Microsoft Visual C++ being out of date. In the error it gives you the link for the update.

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

Go to https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ and click 'Download Build Tools' and install it.

Once it's installed, you'll see a few choices. Select 'C++ build tools' and install it. Restart your computer after it's done. Then run `pip install jupyter` and you should be good!

Comment: 1.11GB Download size; Space 4.4GB

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem on python 3.7.5 when I called

```
pip install jupyter
```

The solution was to first call

```
pip install argon2-cffi==20.1.0
```

And then call

```
  pip install jupyter
```

I think the error is present in the newest version of argon2-cffi. Which is 21.1.0 https://pypi.org/project/argon2-cffi/21.1.0/#history

Answer (score 2):

As the error indicates you need to download [Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=52685).

Comment: Later I downloaded it. But it does not fix the error.

Comment: @PrasadM96  and installed?

Answer (score 2):

In case if other people have problem and in their case that will work.

In my case I used:

```
py -3.8 -m pip install pyautogui
```

That gave me respond:

```
Python 3.8 not found!
Installed Pythons found by C:\Windows\py.exe Launcher for Windows
 -3.9-64 *
 -3.7-64
```

So after I installed Python 3.8 once again used:

```
py -3.8 -m pip install pyautogui
```

Result:

```
Successfully installed PyTweening-1.0.3 mouseinfo-0.1.3 pyautogui-0.9.52 pygetwindow-0.0.9 pymsgbox-1.0.9 pyperclip-1.8.1 pyrect-0.1.4 pyscreeze-0.
```

Comment: You can install in 3.7 itself

Answer (score 1):

**P.S.** [The wheel](https://pypi.org/project/argon2-cffi/#files) is added now

Microsoft Visual C++ 14.2 standalone: Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019 (x86, x64, ARM, ARM64)

This is a standalone version of Visual C++ 14.2 compiler, you don't need to install Visual Studio 2019.

- [Install Microsoft Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019.](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019)
- In Build tools, install C++ build tools and ensure the latest
  versions of MSVCv142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools and Windows 10
  SDK are checked.
- The setuptools Python package version must be at least 34.4.0.

Build Tools also allows us to install any previous Visual C++ 14 version (Including 2015, 2017 ones).

[Source](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_14.2_standalone:_Build_Tools_for_Visual_Studio_2019_.28x86.2C_x64.2C_ARM.2C_ARM64.29https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_14.2_standalone:_Build_Tools_for_Visual_Studio_2019_.28x86.2C_x64.2C_ARM.2C_ARM64.29https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_14.2_standalone:_Build_Tools_for_Visual_Studio_2019_.28x86.2C_x64.2C_ARM.2C_ARM64.29)

1.11 GB Download size; Space 4.4 GB

Answer (score 1):

`argon2-cffi` is now shipping Python 3.9 wheels for Windows which should resolve your installation problem.

Comment: I'm running py 3.9.1 on windows and still get this error when installing pip dependencies

Comment: What is your `pip --version`? Are you on ARM?

Comment: I don't remember. I moved on from the issue. It was python 3.9.1 on windows.