# I can't pip install Jupyter Notebook on Python3.9

Tags: python, pip, jupyter

This is the error that I get when I try to pip install notebook.
I am using Python3.9. I installed VS C++ Build tools and restarted my machine too.
Still can't seem to get jupyter installed, can someone please help with this? Thanks!

````
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\sahi0h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\sahi0h\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\sahi0h\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgkwkmc6k'
       cwd: C:\Users\sahi0h\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-29y4gn0n\argon2-cffi
  Complete output (25 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\low_level.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\_ffi_build.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\_legacy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\_password_hasher.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  running build_clib
  building 'argon2' library
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\extras
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\extras\libargon2
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\extras\libargon2\src
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\extras\libargon2\src\blake2
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Iextras\libargon2\src\..\include -Iextras\libargon2\src\blake2 -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include /Tcextras\libargon2\src\argon2.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\extras\libargon2\src\argon2.obj
  argon2.c
  extras\libargon2\src\argon2.c(18): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'string.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.27.29110\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for argon2-cffi
Failed to build argon2-cffi
ERROR: Could not build wheels for argon2-cffi which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jupyter Notebook installation error - Building wheel for argon2-cffi (PEP 517) ... error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64236463/jupyter-notebook-installation-error-building-wheel-for-argon2-cffi-pep-517)

Answer (score 0):

Found kind of a solution -- I uninstalled Python3.9 and installed Python3.8. Pip install is working now.